# innodb_sort_buffer_size can not change dynamically

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have tried to change "innodb_sort_buffer_size" dinamically in order to improve InnoDB index creation performance.

When I issue a following query(with root user), I got an error "ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_sort_buffer_size' is a read only variable".

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_sort_buffer_size=1024*1024*5;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_sort_buffer_size' is a read only variable
```

As far as I see the document, this variable can change dynamically with SET GLOBAL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_sort_buffer_size

So my question is follows.

- Is this variable really read only?
- Is there another way to improve InnoDB index creation performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is global variable, but it's not dynamic - meaning that it cannot be set at runtime.

Comment: I'm sorry that my response was slow, I have understand this variable is really read only, and documentation was also modified as "dynamic=no". Thank you for your reply.